# Display Custom Module Template After Product Title

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, custom-template

[image]I want to display my custom module template after Product title.

here's the code which I'm using currently.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" as="shippingestimate" template="shippingestimate/shippingdate.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

> Config.xml code

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <shippingestimate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Wtw_Shippingestimate</module>
                    <frontName>shippingestimate</frontName>
                </args>
            </shippingestimate>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <shippingestimate>
                    <file>shippingestimate.xml</file>
                </shippingestimate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</frontend>
```

Just before Qty block.

Thanks

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" as="shippingestimate" template="shippingestimate/shippingdate.phtml" />
  </reference>
 </default>
</layout>

Comment: Can you tell me where you want to show your custom module template? Product Listinfg page or view page etc?

Comment: In your /catalog/product/view.phtml you need to do $this->getChildHtml('shippingestimate'); where you want it to appear

Comment: I'm creating my own custom module so i don't want to make any changes in core files.

Answer (score 1):

**yourlayoutModule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="shippingestimate" template="shippingestimate/shippingdate.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/catalog/product.view.phtml**

and put the piece of code bellow where your want to display your block

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('shippingestimate'); ?>
```

Comment: why `reference name="root"` ? I think it should be `content` instead of `root`

Comment: because Im not using a `structural block`, you have wrong in your solution, but I haven't downvoted you ;)

Comment: So does this means that if we are not adding our xml code in `catalog.xml`, then we can add it in reference `root` and then call anywhere in the template using blockHtml?

Comment: No, When you use `reference name="root"`, you need to render this block in a template  `getChildHtml()` or `getBlockHtml()`, however if you use `reference name="content"` you dont need to render it in a template, it will be added automatically ! why ? because content is a structural block of `core/text_list` type.

Comment: I will try this, +1 for the explanation